# Is there any way to install MS Edge (Chromium) on MacOS without admin?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, microsoft-edge

I use the new Chromium Edge on my Windows VMs and I like it a bit more than Google Chrome. I was trying to replace Chrome with Edge on my Mac, however, while Chrome allows installation in a user's Applications - Edge won't let me install it without elevating to an administrative account.

I'd love to know why this is, but more importantly, is there any way to bypass this?

I've tried installing the Edge Beta - thinking that it could be side-loaded without admin, but that's not the case either. It also wants admin permission to install.

Answer (score 2):

MS Edge still requires administrative privileges to install on MacOS. Use some app like [Suspicious Package](https://mothersruin.com/software/SuspiciousPackage/) which allows you to extract the Microsoft Edge.app from the pkg file and then drag it to `/Applications`. I have used it this way for a few days with no problems whatsoever.

Using this app you can even review the preinstall and postinstall scripts and decide if you want them to run. I noticed that postinstall script does some cleanup if you ever had an older version installed, so this might be good. Both preinstall & postinstall scripts send telemetry data.

The pkg installer also installs `Microsoft AutoUpdate.app` in `/Library/Application Support/Microsoft` folder, which you may or may not want. You may already have this if you got Office installed. There is also an `EdgeUpdater.app` that comes bundled with the main app and is installed in the user's `~/Library/Microsoft/EdgeUpdater/` folder (hence no password required), so I wouldn't think the AutoUpdate app is mandatory to install in order to perform updates.

Comment: I tried using Pacifist to do this and got so many alerts on OS X Ventura that I gave up. I never knew about this FREE app. I just tried it and was able to extract both apps no problem. Thanks for recommending a Pacifist replacement.

Answer (score 0):

Chromium Edge requires admin credentials on most systems: All Windows, Linux that I have tried, but not Raspberry PI (which does not have a user admin concept).

I agree Chromium Edge is an excellent browser, so just provide Admin Credentials when asked.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I know I'm able to provide admin credentials - but I was hoping for a way around that, as I maintain all of my non-Apple applications as user level permissions. It's unfortunate that MS would add the admin requirement